# Filtro de produto no Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filtro

Preciso criar um filtro de produtos igual a este, mas não tenho conhecimentos suficientes para criar do zero.

[image: Filtro de produtos no Woocommerce]

Alguém poderia me indicar um plugin para Wordpress que me dessa essa possibilidade ou me ensinar como eu faço para copiar esse filtro do site em que estou me baseando e aplicar no meu?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fala parceiro.

Cara, acho que você conseguiria com esse plugin aqui: https://facetwp.com/ .. porém ele é pago.

Já fiz algumas coisas legais com ele em projetos. É bem útil.

Dá uma olhada nesse link demonstrando como integrar:
https://facetwp.com/integration-with-woocommerce-and-the-storefront-theme/

Também existe esse aqui: http://wpadvancedsearch.com/ .. só que não cheguei a utilizar ele especificamente integrado ao Woocommerce. No caso aí você teria que pesquisar mais a fundo e entender melhor como seria possível.

Espero ter ajudado.

Vlw!

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, acabei encontrando um outro plugin chamado "WOOF" e meio que consegui fazer por ele, agora só preciso configurar o css pra ficar como no exemplo, as demais funções estão funcionando perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Comment: Show! Vou até dar uma olhada nesse que você encontrou. Valeu.